# How to display all inserted integers by user with list?

Tags: c#, list, int

i read all articles with similar theme, but i couldnt find solution that suits me. I am at beginning of learning C# and i wrote simple code (guess number from 1 to 100) with arrays. When user hits correct number, application shows all inserted numbers by user.
These days i am learning Lists. I want to write similar code, but with List, to limit tries at 10 and display all inserted numbers. Cant figure out how to memorize all inserted numbers with List. I found on several places command *out* but is there any simple way to do this. If i understand Lists are more practical then arrays. I dont need to determine how many tries could user have...
Obviously, it isnt enough to write InsertedNumber.Add(c)
Code is simple and short, i think i can copy all of it. Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int b = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            int c;
            int NumberOfTries = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Guess number from 1 to 100. You have 10 tries.");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 10) { Console.WriteLine("\nYou tried 10 times. Game is 
 over!"); break; }
                Console.Write("\nGuess number: ");
                List<int> InsertedNumbers = new List<int>();
                c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                InsertedNumbers.Add(c);
                    if (c == b)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bravo. You had {0} tries.", NumberOfTries);
                        foreach (var item in InsertedNumbers)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < InsertedNumbers.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", InsertedNumbers[j]);
                        }
                         break;
                    }
                    else if (c < b)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No. My number is larger then " + c);
                        NumberOfTries++;
                    }
                    else if (c > b)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No. My number is smaller then " + c);
                        NumberOfTries++;
                    }
            } 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is the code working? If so you can ask on codereview. / What's the question? I can't understand. / Minimal example please.

Comment: So you want to convert from arrays to a list. thats fine, but you need to ask a specific question.. as your "it isnt enough to write insertednumber.add(c)" why not?

Comment: Could you please post the inputs and the expected output? like what do you want to see in the end?

Comment: At the end (after user hits correct number, or he is out of 10 times guessing) i want to present user all numbers that he inserted.Now, when user hits correct number, application shows that number twice, and thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: *extract methods*, do not *cram everything* into single `Main`. When `InsertedNumbers` is a `PlayGame`'s *local variable* it's by far easier to maintain.
If you want to print out all `InsertedNumbers` items you can try using `String.Join` method

```
   private static int GuessNumber() {
     Console.Write("\nGuess number: ");

     int result = 0; 

     // Check User Input: what if the inserted value is "bla-bla-bla"? 
     while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))         
       Console.WriteLine("Incorrect format; please, put an integer value");

     return result; 
   }

   private static void PlayGame(int value, int maxTries = 10) {
     List<int> InsertedNumbers = new List<int>();

     while (InsertedNumbers.Count < maxTries) {
       int guess = GuessNumber();

       InsertedNumbers.Add(guess);

       if (guess < value)
         Console.WriteLine($"No. My number is larger then {guess}"); 
       else if (guess > value)
         Console.WriteLine($"No. My number is smaller then {guess}");
       else {
         Console.WriteLine($"Bravo. You had {InsertedNumbers.Count} tries.");
         // Combine all items in InsertedNumbers into single string
         Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, InsertedNumbers));

         return;
       }
     }

     Console.WriteLine("\nYou tried maxTries times. Game is  over!");
   }
```

Finally

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    PlayGame(rnd.Next(1, 100), 10); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi if I'm understanding your Question correctly your printing of the List of quessed number did not work correctly.

This is because you create a new List every iteration of your loop. So everything works correctly. But every iteration you create a new List overwriting the one from your previous iteration. So just create your List once before you start iterating and everything should be fine.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> InsertedNumbers = new List<int>(); //Create List before the loop
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int b = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        int c;
        int NumberOfTries = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Guess number from 1 to 100. You have 10 tries.");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou tried 10 times. Game is over!");
                break;
            }

            Console.Write("\nGuess number: ");
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            InsertedNumbers.Add(c);

            if (c == b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bravo. You had {0} tries.", NumberOfTries);
                foreach (int item in InsertedNumbers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < InsertedNumbers.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", InsertedNumbers[j]);
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (c < b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No. My number is larger then " + c);
                NumberOfTries++;
            }
            else if (c > b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No. My number is smaller then " + c);
                NumberOfTries++;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: The last if is superfluent. If c is not <= b, then it must be >

Comment: That is it :) Thank you MaDOS very much. Do you know that i spent last 30hours trying to figure out how?...I had twice result because i had same for and foreach loops in (if c== b)

Comment: _" overwriting the one from your previous iteration"_ - not exactly. The one from the previous iteration is out of scope. So it is not really "overwritten" but for the current iteration it is a completely new one and we do not know of any previous ones. If the variable had been declared outside and just assigned a new instance inside, then the reference would have been "overwritten".